# webpack | what does [query] mean in assetModuleFilename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]'?

Tags: webpack, assets, loader

[image]

https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#custom-output-filename

I know `[hash]` stands for random number and alphabet, and `[ext]` stands for Filename Extension.

But I don't know what is `[query]` and the use of it.

Comment: Hello, did you find the answer to this at the end? Looking for the same, thank you in advance and regards

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/364

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the webpack docs

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/

> Substitutions available on File-level:
>
> [query]   Query with leading ?